# Как с помощью vue.js пользоваться ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, vue.js

Мне нужно сделать проверку инпута, с помощью `vue.js`, без нажатия на `submit`, которая будет проверять наличие логина в БД (проверяется в php файле).

Если есть данный логин, то с помощью `vue.js` изменяется классы в html файле, но у меня не получается отправлять запросы не нажимая на клавишу submit, т.е. мне надо чтобы запрос отправлялся сразу же, как я ввожу в инпут хотя бы что-то.

Вот немножко код `HTML`:

```
        <div id = "test" class = "form-group row">
            <input class = 'form-control col-sm-4' type = "text" v-model="message">
            <input  type = "button"  class = "form-control btn col-sm-2" value = "something" v-bind:class="{' btn-outline-success': !error(), ' btn btn-outline-danger': error() }" /><br>
            <p id = "alert" ><p>
        </div>
```

Вот код js:

```
 var test = new Vue({
        el: '#test',
        data: {
            message: ''
        },
        methods: {
            check(){
                var login = this.message;

                var message = 'something';
                $.get('check.php', {check_login:login}, function(data)  {
                    $("#alert").html(data);//Здесь я просто проверяю что вывелось в php, и вывелось ли 
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Вот код php:

```
include_once('settings.php');

$login = $_POST['check_login'];

$sql_login = sprintf("SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = '$login'");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_login);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row){
    echo true;
}
else 
    echo false;
```

Comment: В руководстве vue есть шикарный пример, не помню раздел только. Там отслеживается message и пропускается через тормозилку debounce.

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8

Comment: npm install axios -save

Comment: @МаксимК, спасибо, как-то пропустил мимо глаз этот раздел)